# Stripe create Checkout session only with total price

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm currently working in a (small) project where we want to create a shop but we aren't selling anything yet.
We are storing our products that we want to sell in our own database.
However I wanted to implement a feature that simulates the payment of an order and I was recommended to use Stripe for it.
However as far as I know I can't create a checkout session without providing a list of products stored in my Stripe account?
So I would need to create all the products in Stripe as well (and have them in my own database too)

Is there no way to just create a checkout session with a total price and when the payment succeeds I can move on?

Answer (score 21):

Yes it’s possible to use Checkout without creating products and prices in Stripe. You need to pass the [`line_items.price_data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items) object as a parameter when creating the CheckoutSession in order to specify the details of the payment inline (or "ad-hoc").

Here’s an example of how it could look like in node.js:

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  line_items: [
    {
      price_data: {
        currency: "usd",
        unit_amount: 500,
        product_data: {
          name: "name of the product",
        },
      },
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  mode: "payment",
  success_url: "http://example.com/success",
  cancel_url: "http://example.com/",
});
```

You can learn more about Checkout on this [documentation page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#redirect-customers).

Comment: what are the pros and cons of passing a full price_data object or just a price id?

Comment: When using a price ID with Checkout Sessions you get access to more features. For example [cross-sell](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/cross-sells) and [upsell](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/upsells).

Comment: Another document -> https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data